# Homotopy class of maps from torus to BG for a group G

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I find a statement that the set of pairs of commuting elements in a group G is bijective to the set of homotopy classes of maps from torus to BG, the classifying space in the paper [Elliptic cohomology](http://http://www.numdam.org/item?id=SB_1987-1988__30__187_0/) I was wondering whether there is a simple proof or some other references for this statement.

Comment: This is true only if $G$ is discrete, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36488/how-to-compute-homotopy-classes-of-maps-on-the-2-torus/36504#36504 and use that $G\sim \Omega BG$, so $\pi_1(BG)=\pi_0(G),\pi_2(BG)=\pi_1(G)$.

Comment: Note that the set of pairs of commuting elements in $G$ is in bijections with $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2,G)$.

Comment: Could you fix your link?  Even after inserting a colon after the http, Numdam said that the document wasn't found.

Comment: The claim is slightly incorrect as stated; either you should take pointed homotopy or you should quotient by conjugation by $G$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not much more than an extended version of the two coments above.

For discrete groups $\Gamma, G$ it is true that $${\pi_1}_{\ast}\colon [B\Gamma,BG] \to \text{Hom}(\Gamma,G)$$
is a bijection, see e.g. the first chapter of Mosher-Tangora.

In particular, for $\Gamma = \mathbb Z^2$ we get $$[T^2,BG] \cong \text{Hom}(\mathbb Z^2,G) = \{g,h \in G : gh = hg\}.$$
For $G$ non-discrete however, this fails to be true; take e.g. $G = S^1$ so that $BG = \mathbb CP^{\infty}$. Then
$$[T^2,BS^1] = [T^2,S^2] = \mathbb Z,$$
but the space of commuting elements in $G$ is $S^1 \times S^1 = T^2$.